# Using elm-test in a git hub action

Tags: elm, github-actions, elm-test

I want to use the an git hub action to test and build my elm package whenever a commit is pushed to the master branch for this my action `.yml` file looks like this

```
name: CI

on: [push]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Setup Elm environment
      uses: JorelAli/setup-elm@v1
      with:
        # Version of Elm to use. E.g. 0.19.1
        elm-version: 0.19.1
    - run: |
        sudo npm install -g elm-test # this fails
        elm-test
        elm make
```

for testing I want to use `elm-test` which can be installed via `npm` but the command `sudo npm install -g elm-test` fails with

```
/usr/local/bin/elm-test -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/elm-test/bin/elm-test

> elmi-to-json@1.3.0 install /usr/local/lib/node_modules/elm-test/node_modules/elmi-to-json
> binwrap-install

ERR Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/elm-test/node_modules/elmi-to-json/unpacked_bin'
    at Object.mkdirSync (fs.js:823:3)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/elm-test/node_modules/binwrap/binstall.js:46:10
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at untgz (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/elm-test/node_modules/binwrap/binstall.js:21:10)
    at binstall (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/elm-test/node_modules/binwrap/binstall.js:11:12)
    at install (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/elm-test/node_modules/binwrap/install.js:20:10)
    at Object.install (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/elm-test/node_modules/binwrap/index.js:14:14)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/elm-test/node_modules/binwrap/bin/binwrap-install:18:9)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:955:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:991:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:811:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:14)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1043:10)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:11 {
  errno: -13,
  syscall: 'mkdir',
  code: 'EACCES',
  path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/elm-test/node_modules/elmi-to-json/unpacked_bin'
}
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.1.2 (node_modules/elm-test/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.1.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! elmi-to-json@1.3.0 install: `binwrap-install`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the elmi-to-json@1.3.0 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/runner/.npm/_logs/2020-02-03T17_50_06_232Z-debug.log
```

Any advice on how to install `elm-test` inside a git hub action?

Edit:
Without the `sudo` the error becomes

```
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! syscall access
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'
npm ERR!  [Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'] {
npm ERR!   stack: "Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'",
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'access',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/runner/.npm/_logs/2020-02-04T13_41_34_534Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Don't use `sudo`? You should never use `sudo` with npm or any other package manager, in CI or otherwise.

Comment: Okay, but how else can I set up `elm-test` in CI

Comment: By not using `sudo`, first of all. Have you tried that yet?

Comment: @glennsl Yes, see my edit

Comment: Ok, so seems like `npm` is set up incorrectly on the image you're using. You can fix that by following this guide: https://docs.npmjs.com/resolving-eacces-permissions-errors-when-installing-packages-globally

Comment: That has done the trick @glennsl if you write it as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: Great! I think it'd be better if you answered it yourself and included the actual yml file, since that's what the question asks for. I don't mind :)

Comment: You likely want `elm-test` installed locally to your project in the `package.json` so it versioned to not break against other projects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @toastal comment I found another solution. That is to set up a `package.json` file using `npm` and then adding `elm-test` as a dependency with the command

```
npm install -D elm-test
```

also you might want to add `node_modules` to your `.gitignore` to ignore `npm`s installation folder.

Then in the `yml` file you can just run the command `npm install` and `elm-test` gets installed.
Then you can call it with

```
./node_modules/elm-test/bin/elm-test
```

My `yml` file now looks like this

```
name: Tests

on: [push]

jobs:
  test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Setup Elm environment
      uses: JorelAli/setup-elm@v1
      with:
        # Version of Elm to use. E.g. 0.19.1
        elm-version: 0.19.1
    - name: install npm dependencies
      run: npm install
    - name: Test
      run: ./node_modules/elm-test/bin/elm-test
    - name: check documentation
      run: |
        elm make --docs=docs.json
        rm docs.json
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @glennsl I found a solution: specifying where npm installs package globally.
Since the runner that runs the action has no access to the `/usr/local/lib` npm can't install anything on a global level.
The solution (as described [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/resolving-eacces-permissions-errors-when-installing-packages-globally)) is to create a folder as a *"global"* installation folder and configuring npm to use it. It is also necessary to add the new folder to the `PATH` environment variable.

So my `yml` file now looks like this

```
name: CI

on: [push]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Setup Elm environment
      uses: JorelAli/setup-elm@v1
      with:
        # Version of Elm to use. E.g. 0.19.1
        elm-version: 0.19.1
    - run: |
        mkdir ~/.npm-global
        npm config set prefix '~/.npm-global'
        PATH=~/.npm-global/bin:$PATH
        npm install -g elm-test
        elm-test
        elm make
```